# Flutter Push Notification and Background fetch

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, fetch, push

I want  to trigger  fetch data on PUSH notification . It works fine when the app is in foreground.  If the app is in background the notification popup but the fetch data from url not fire. any idea why . For notification I am using  Firebase Cloud Messaging. My intention is to fetch data from API when there is any notification.